# using form from a dll as MDIChild

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dll

I'm new to C# and .Net and I have a question about Forms and dll's:
I want use dll's like plugins, each dll contains a Form that should be used as a MDIChild. 
When I click on a defined Button the dll-Form should be displayed.

What to do? I have the calling .exe and the .dll with the Form and some Controls on it.
Connection to the dll is ok, calling a function from the dll works as expected.

But how to show the Form as a MDIChild?

Name of the class in dll is 'myDllChildForm'

Thanks in advance

JustMe

Comment: Start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-mdi-child-forms).

Answer (score 0):

Dll's are created using class library. A simpler approach would be to create your plugins as DLL's which have the logic. You can expose certain function from the dll package which your clients can consume or call from child forms